# How to get sim id from iphone

Tags: ios

I'm new to ios i'm working in a small project in that i need to get sim Identification number so please tell is there any way to get sim id from iphone...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way using official APIs.

Comment: No,There is a way to get this values but if we implement in any app apple will reject that app from appstore.

Comment: Right, hence "there is no way using official APIs"